# Problems with sort and IComparable

Tags: c#, icomparable

I'm trying to sort an `ArrayList` of custom items and get 'At least one object must implement IComparable.' despite having implemented the `IComparable` interface for them.  I'm just calling the default `Sort()` no parameters or anything.  The definition of the object I'm trying to sort is as follows:

```
class AssetItem : System.IComparable<AssetItem>
{
        public string AssetName { get; set; }
        public int AssetID { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(AssetItem item)
        {
            if (null == item)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (this.AssetID < item.AssetID)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (this.AssetID == item.AssetID)
            {
                return this.AssetName.CompareTo(item.AssetName);
            }
            else
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
```

This code builds just fine.  One more thing to keep in mind, and I suspect this may be the issue though I don't understand how, the class above is an inner class.  If that is what's tripping me up, how would you go about comparing an inner class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've implemented `IComparable<T>`, not `IComparable`. They're different interfaces. If you're going to use generics, just use `List<T>` to start with. I mean you *could* also implement `IComparable`, but I'd just move away from the somewhat-obsolete nongeneric collections if I were you.

Comment: I had the same problem, thanks! It makes me wonder though, why doesn't IComparable<T> inherit from IComparable?

Comment: @jrummell: That would force it to try to compare itself with *any* object, instead of just objects of the right type, which is a bit of a pain.

Answer (score 3):

Can you use LINQ in your project? If so, and if all you need is sorting by a property, you don't need to implement IComparable. You could just do:

```
theAssetsList.OrderBy(asset => asset.AssetId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try..
list= new List(list.OrderBy(x => x.Text));